# Удаление узлов DOM дерева

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите , удаляю узел через x.remove(). В значение х записывается ссылка на этот узел. Как правильно очистить  x?

```
var x =document.getElementById("number"+String(i));
        x.remove();
```

Comment: ваш `x` будет только в одной области видимости, зачем его чистить? Вы работаете с динамическим языком

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id

Comment: @ilyaplot Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Да просто.

```
document.getElementById('number'+String(i)).remove();
```

В данном вами примере переменная `x` лишняя.

P.S. Ещё можно объявлять переменную не через `var`, а через [let](https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const), чтобы сузить область видимости от функции до блока, конечно если вы не собираетесь её использовать вне текущего блока.